# Задать элемент списка суммой переменной и другого элемента этого же списка

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

С помощью библиотеки `Canvas` (`tkinter`) мне нужно нарисовать круг.
У меня есть к нему список из четырёх элементов - точки начала и конца круга, а также две переменные: длина и ширина.

```
plW = 30 # Width
plH = 30 # Height
plSets = [10, 10, 40, 40]
```

Предпоследний элемент должен равняться сумме длины и первого элемента, последний тоже - сумме ширины и второго элемента.

Как это делать? Помогите

Comment: У круга нет ни начала, ни конца, ни длины, ни ширины.

Comment: Считай сумму двух элементов, присваивай третьему. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто формировать список сразу с результатами вычислений:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

width = 30 # ширина
height = 40 # высота
x = 20
y = 10
coords = [x, y, x + width, y + height]
canvas.create_oval(coords)

root.mainloop()
```